# Google Compute Engine - Allow port 3389 on GCP and Firewall but still blocked

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2019

I have a virtual machine (Windows Server 2019) running on Google's Compute Engine and I need to allow port 3389 to Remote Desktop Connections but I have allowed it on GCP and firewall but it still blocked. I've been trying to fix the problem for days. What could be happening? image of the rules below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf8kQ.png

Comment: Show your Google Firewall rule for this instance. Did you enable Remote Desktop under System Properties -> Rmote? Which version of Windows are you using to connect to Window Server 2019?

Comment: Hello, John. First of all, I use Windows 10. Remote Desktop is enabled and the connection works with other ports (for exemple, 3992). The problem happened only with port 3389.

Comment: Is your Internet provider blocking port 3389? Post the output from `curl -v <WINDOWS_IP>:3389`

Comment: Can you post the error message you are seeing when trying to connect? Also, are you able to RDP on different devices or VM? Lastly, you can also use this web [NMAP](https://nmap.online/) tool to check if the VM's 3389 port is open.

Comment: John
curl -v :

curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -v 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: Alex:

ERROR MENSAGE:
Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons
1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Comment: NMAP:

Host is up (0.0084s latency).
Not shown: 85 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp    closed ftp
22/tcp    closed ssh
80/tcp    open   http
443/tcp   closed https
1433/tcp  open   ms-sql-s
3306/tcp  closed mysql
3389/tcp  closed ms-wbt-server
8080/tcp  open   http-proxy
8081/tcp  closed blackice-icecap
49152/tcp closed unknown
49153/tcp closed unknown
49154/tcp closed unknown
49155/tcp closed unknown
49156/tcp closed unknown
49157/tcp closed unknown

Comment: Your curl output is not from the CLI curl.exe but from PowerShell's implementation of curl.

Comment: John:
Rebuilt URL to: SERVER IP:3389/
  Trying SERVER IP...
TCP_NODELAY set
connect to SERVER IP port 3389 failed: Connection refused
Failed to connect to SERVER IP port 3389: Connection refused
Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to SERVER IP port 3389: Connection refused